# Ошибка в TOR браузере на iOS при установке Websocket соединения: Can't find variable: __endless

Tags: javascript, node.js, ios, websocket, tor

Есть websocket сервер на Node.JS который спрятан за TOR и доступен по
onion ссылке. На клиенте я пытаюсь установить websocket соединение с сервером. Код клиента:

```
function testWebsocket() {
    try {

        let endpoint = document.location.host
        console.log("Connecting to " + endpoint + "   ...")    
        let s = new WebSocket("ws://" + endpoint)

        s.addEventListener('open', function () {
            console.log("Connection established");
        });


        s.onerror = function (err) {
            throw ('Connection Failed');
        }


        s.onmessage = function(msg){
            console.log("MESSAGE: " + msg);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("!! ERROR: " + err.toString())
    }

}
```

Все отлично отрабатывает на Tor браузерах в Android, Windows, MacOS, но на iOS девайсах выдает следующую ошибку:

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __endless